# Z-Index property not working over a youtube video

Tags: asp.net, html, css, youtube, z-index

My site is in VB using VS 2010, and my z-index property I have set to 20, and it's working fine over pictures and other things.  But I have two youtube videos, and the z-index property isn't working; the menu I want to display is covered up by the youtube video -- but only in IE; other browsers work fine!

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is there something I should do differently when it's a youtube video?

My embedded video looks like this and it's covering my menu:

```
<table class="tablestyle0">
<tr>
<td>
<iframe id="ShowFrameID" width="640" height="480"            
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IxiZ0sdh6hw?wmode=opaque?        
modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0">
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
```

Any help or guidance in this regard would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `wmode=opaque` to `wmode=transparent`, then the YouTube player should respect your z-index ordering.

**EDIT:** The problem is you have two `?` characters in your YouTube URL. The wmode=opaque part is not getting through to the server.

It worked for me after I made that change. You probably don't have to set it to `transparent` (`opaque` should work, too).

```
<table class="tablestyle0">
<tr>
<td>
<iframe id="ShowFrameID" width="640" height="480"            
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IxiZ0sdh6hw?wmode=opaque&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0">
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to read and respond to my issue, jimp.  I followed your instructions, and I still get the same error; the menu is covered up by the video.  But I only have issues with IE; Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all respect the Z-index property.

Comment: Which version of IE? Older IE versions (before 9 I think?) are known to have z-index ordering bug that does not follow the standard. Basically, the [z-index stack resets to 0 for each positioned element](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html). Maybe that is your problem.

Comment: Hi Jimp.  IE9.  My site is in 10 different languages, and here's what my products.master looks like:  <div class="youtube"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="productsmastercolumn" 
        Text=""></asp:Label></div>

Comment: And here's what I added to site.css:  div.youtube
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px; 
-moz-border-radius: 3px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
border: 0px solid #800000;
z-index:20;
}

Comment: If you can give a link to the site that I can load up in IE9, I'd be happy to see if I can reproduce the problem. It's obviously not the conventional YouTube z-index issue and must be something specific to IE's interpretation of CSS.

Comment: Sure, it's http://www.ussvision.com/products/exactscan ..... and thank you very much for taking the time to try to help me out, Jimp.

Comment: Absolutely worked!  Thank you for your time and patience, Jimp -- I truly appreciate your help, especially considering more people view my site in IE than any other browser.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to your table class' CSS and it should honor the z-index after that.

Comment: Thanks Cynthia for taking the time to read and respond.  I was working with @Jimp, and finally solved the issue.  I have plenty of more videos, and I'll try your solution next.  Thanks again!